# Number notation "SK"

Tags: parsing, odbc, number-formatting, ampl

I use an ODBC table handler to read data from Excel and CSV files into an AMPL model. But the thing I encountered probably doesn't have much to do with the precise programs and programming language I use.

Among the data are two specific types of strings: three-digit alphabetic and six-digit alphanumeric.

When the three-digit alphabetic type includes a `NAN` string, AMPL throws an error. As I found out, the reason is that it understands `NAN` as "NaN" (not a number). It cannot use this as an index.

The six-digit alphanumeric type sometimes include strings like `3E1234`. This seems to be a problem because AMPL (or the handler) understands this as a number in scientific notation. So it reads `3*10^1234`, which is handled as infinity. So when there is one `3E1234` entry and one `3E1235` entry, it sees them both as infinity.

I understand these two. And although they are annoying, I can work with that. Now I encountered that a string `SK1234` is parsed as the number 1234. I have learned a bit of programming in college, but I don't have any idea why this happens. Is the prefix `SK` anything special?

**EDIT:** Here is an example that reproduces the error:

The model file:

```
set INDEX;
param value;
```

The "run" file:

```
table Table1 IN "tableproxy" "odbc" "DSN=NDE" "Test.csv": INDEX <- [Index], value ~ Value;
read table Table1;
```

`NDE` is a user DSN that uses the Microsoft Text Driver in the appropriate folder.
And the CSV file:

```
Index,Value
SK1202,1
SK1445,2
SK0124,3
SK7896,4
SK1,5
AB1234,6
```

After running all this code, I type `display INDEX` and get

```
set INDEX := 1202 1445 124 7896 1 Missing;
```

So the field `Index` is treated as a numeric field with the first five entries converted to a number. The last entry cannot be converted so it is treated as `Missing`.

The DSN's setting is that it sets the type according to the first 25 lines. For some reason, it understands the `SK...` entries as numbers and therefore reads all as numbers.

Comment: Could you post the AMPL code that you use to read the data?

Comment: @vitaut: I added an example CSV "file" and the code.

Answer (score 0):

For the Text ODBC driver to detect column type correctly, values should be quoted:

```
Index,Value
'SK1202',1
'SK1445',2
'SK0124',3
'SK7896',4
'SK1',5
'AB1234',6
```

Comment: I found that out in the meantime as well. But _why_ are these values read as numbers?

Comment: @KarlKlammer That's just the way automatic type detection in this ODBC driver works. You can override it using schema.ini: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(VS.85).aspx